# NSThread setThreadPriority: is not working

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsthread

I am using `+ (BOOL)setThreadPriority:(double)p;` to change priority of `NSThread` but `threadPriority` is always 0.5. Return value of `setThreadPriority:` is `TURE`.

```
_thread =  [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(runThread) object:nil];

-(void)runThread {
    @autoreleasepool {
        [[NSThread currentThread] setName:@"3DF7EF974A80"];
        NSRunLoop *runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
        [runLoop addPort:[NSMachPort port] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [_condition lock];
        [_condition signal];
        [_condition unlock];
        [NSThread setThreadPriority:1.0];
        CFRunLoopRun();

        [runLoop removePort:[NSMachPort port] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [_condition lock];
        [_condition signal];
        [_condition unlock];
    }
}
```

I am using Xcode 7.0.1 and OS X 10.10.5.

Comment: When you called this, did it return `TRUE` or `FALSE`? Did you call this on a thread you manually created yourself?

Comment: it return TRUE. I am creating thread manually. I have added code.

Comment: did you try to set thread priority after run loop run statement?

Comment: @Astoria that will get called only if you stop _thread.

Comment: Any difference if you do `[[NSThread currentThread] setThreadPriority:1.0]`?  Perhaps the class method is not working properly?

Comment: I just tested this code and it set the priority fine. Where are you checking the `threadPriority`? Are you checking it from within that thread? Or are you checking it from the main thread, perhaps immediately after you instantiated/started this secondary thread (in which case `runThread` may not have run yet.

Comment: @Rob I am calling function on runThread using - (void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector onThread:(NSThread *)thr withObject:(nullable id)arg waitUntilDone:(BOOL)wait and checking priority inside aSelector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the behavior you describe. When I do the following on either iOS or Mac OS X, it correctly sets the thread priority:

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSThread *_thread;
    NSCondition *_condition;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _condition = [[NSCondition alloc] init];
    _thread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(runThread) object:nil];
    [_thread start];
    [self performSelector:@selector(checkThreadStatus) onThread:_thread withObject:nil waitUntilDone:false];
}

- (void)checkThreadStatus {
    NSLog(@"%.2f", [[NSThread currentThread] threadPriority]);
}

- (void)runThread {
    @autoreleasepool {
        [[NSThread currentThread] setName:@"3DF7EF974A80"];
        NSRunLoop *runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
        [runLoop addPort:[NSMachPort port] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [_condition lock];
        [_condition signal];
        [_condition unlock];
        [NSThread setThreadPriority:1.0];
        CFRunLoopRun();

        [runLoop removePort:[NSMachPort port] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [_condition lock];
        [_condition signal];
        [_condition unlock];
    }
}

@end
```

We need [minimal, yet reproducible, example of the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to help you diagnose this further.

Answer (score 0):

setThreadPriority doesn't work on simulator, please check this on device

Comment: This question is for OS X.